# How to modify MSR_LSTAR register without inducing system freezing

Tags: linux-kernel, cpu, system-calls, kernel-module

I developed a kernel module in order to setup another syscall_64 trampoline. In order to do that I have to change MSR_LSTAR register value with the address of my trampoline.
I tried to change MSR_LSTAR register value on all cpus available through on_each_cpu function and wrmsrl function.

This induces my system to freeze / hang, so I have to forcing power off and then reboot.

No logs are produced from this action and no kernel-panic.

I tried also to change MSR_LSTAR to 0 in order to make every user-task to crash as a result, but the system freeze and no logs no panic.

I tested it on a Lenovo IdeaPad 330 mounting linux-kernel-5.0.11 with a amd-a6 processor arch: x86_64.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: :) do not waste your time. Modifying MSR_LSTAR etc. registers available only in zero ring context. These are privileged instructions. I tried to run such code written in assembler 64bit but I got only process crashes. EXCEPTION_PRIV_INSTRUCTION